# Inserting data without naming columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having a problem with inserting data.

Let's assume we have 2 tables.

The first table is as the following:

```
Table:customer
Column:a b c d e f
```

And the second one is

```
Table:customer2
Column:a b c d e f g
```

As you can see, they are the same except one column is added on the second table.

Now I am trying to execute this sql statement.

```
Insert into customer 
Select * from customer2
```

You will know what result will be without thinking.

Is there any methed to get this done.
I mean data on the customer2 table need to be inserted into table customer, column g aside.

Listing column names are not allowed because this is done promatically.
Tens of varios tables with various of columns names exist on the oracle server.

Only pure sql is allowed...

Answer (score 3):

> Only pure sql is allowed

Having the required **column list** in the **SELECT** statement is also *pure SQL*. It shouldn't be a difficult task to list the required column names in the SELECT statement using a good *text editor*. For developers, this shouldn't be an excuse.

```
Insert into customer 
Select a, b, c, d, e, f from customer2;
```

**Update** An example to build the **INSET SELECT..** script.

Using **USER_TAB_COLS** view and **LISTAGG** function(or an equivalent prior to 11g), I could build the insert script:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE emp1 AS SELECT * FROM emp WHERE 1 = 2;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> set linesize 150
SQL>
SQL> SELECT 'INSERT INTO emp1('
  2    ||listagg(column_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (
  3  ORDER BY column_name)
  4    ||') SELECT '
  5    ||listagg(column_name, ',') within GROUP (
  6  ORDER BY column_name)
  7    ||' FROM emp' insert_script
  8  FROM user_tab_cols
  9  WHERE table_name='EMP';

INSERT_SCRIPT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO emp1(COMM,DEPTNO,EMPNO,ENAME,HIREDATE,JOB,MGR,SAL) SELECT COMM,DEPTNO,EMPNO,ENAME,HIREDATE,JOB,MGR,SAL FROM emp

SQL>
```

So, my insert script is ready. now let' test it:

```
SQL> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM emp1;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO emp1(COMM,DEPTNO,EMPNO,ENAME,HIREDATE,JOB,MGR,SAL)
  2    SELECT COMM,DEPTNO,EMPNO,ENAME,HIREDATE,JOB,MGR,SAL FROM emp;

14 rows created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM emp1;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        14

SQL>
```

Works perfectly!

Comment: I know this . The problem is column names are all diffrent across tables on the database.

Comment: Different tables, different column names, different insert queries. I don't see how is this a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Ok..

1. If you can hard-code the table name in the query, I believe you can construct the query with the column names as well.

But if you want this operation in many such tables, Then PL/SQL will help greatly, If PLSQL is out of scope for you, you may make use of USER_TAB_COLS where you can get the columns present in both the tables and later use the following in your insert statement. All this be done dynamically in a sql insert query itself.

Comment: You should not do it in PL/SQL when the same could be done in pure SQL.

Answer (score 0):

just do the following

```
Insert into customer 
Select a, b, c, d, e, f from customer2;
```